# Python - Building a dynamic sql query with `-` as a range

Tags: python, python-2.7, arcpy

I've done some searching and thought I'd ask before trying to reinvent the wheel.

I'm looking to build a sql query with an unknown number of parameters. The parameters are of type int, they are item numbers.

The user can input as many items as they like, in the form 1, 2, 3-10, 12

I need to build a sql style query (actually for arcpy) that will return all these values for field item.

I can easily pull these all into a list such as
    mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

But then I need to build the query, I'm guess it would be something like

```
item = 1 or item = 2 or ......
```

Thanks very much

Jon

Comment: you mean "select * from your_table where id in (1,2,3,4,5,6)" ??

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can do it this way,

```
user_input = '1, 2, 3-10, 12'
data = [item for item in user_input.split(', ')]
result = []

for d in data:
    if '-' in d:
        result.extend(range(int(d.partition('-')[0], int(d.partition('-')[2])+2))
    else:
        result.append(int(d))
```

Check what result is,

```
>>> result
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12]
```

Query it,

```
'SELECT * FROM table WHERE id in (%s)' % ','.join(str(item) for item in result)
```

Comment: @jpedder make sure that you're not using this with untrusted input. Using string interpolation to generate SQL queries leaves you wide open to SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

if sql style query is fully supported, you could put it in a list, and generate the query like this:

```
items = [1,2,3,4,5]
query = 'select * from table where item in (%s)' % ','.join(items)
```